# WAMP server - when I go to my IP address it doesn't redirect to index.php

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp

I downloaded WAMP server (PHP and Apache and MySQL) and I have a problem. When I am on localhost all works fine, but when I access my public IP from a browser, it says:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

When I add `index.php`to the end of the URL it works fine.

I already tried adding a DirectoryIndex index.php line to .htaccess but without effect.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may have not enough permission to access your localhost with your local ip address. try this,

**Solution :**

- Go to C:\WAMP\bin\apache\apache2.2.17\conf (version may change)
- Open httpd.conf file in notepad.
- Find the section given below. By default it will be like this.

  `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">`
      `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`
      `AllowOverride all`
      `Order Deny,Allow`
      `Deny from all`
      `Allow from 127.0.0.1`
  `</Directory>`>
- Now change this section as given below.

  `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">`
      `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`
      `AllowOverride all`
      `Order Deny,Allow`
      `#Deny from all`
      `#Allow from 127.0.0.1`
      `Allow from all`
  `</Directory>`
- Restart apache service.
- Now you will be able to get the localhost by using your local ip address also.

Good luck Bro :)

Comment: I already solved it, but still thanks for answer :)